# Need all the jar files to use Rest Assured in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rest, web-services, rest-assured, junit5

Can someone provide me the link to download all the jar(s) for restassured to use in eclipse.

I am using a normal java project (not maven) and trying to create a test case for a web service.

When I add restassured3.0.0.jar to eclipse, I was getting class not found exceptions and I added all the required jar files.

This how my library looks like (see in image).

[image]

Now, I remained with the error,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/mapper/factory/GsonObjectMapperFactory
```

Please help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.0/

You can download all JAR's you need from http://mvnrepository.com

Comment: Added the jar to buildpath and getting this error

 **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     
    io/restassured/mapper/factory/ObjectMapperFactory**

Comment: That's another dependency you're missing, RestAssured needs Jackson JSON Parser, from https://github.com/FasterXML, find it on the MVN repo and include it.

Comment: Because you're not using Maven, Rest Assured can't download the dependencies it needs. Most of today libraries rely on other libraries to do not specialized work.
This are the RestAssured dependencies in their pom.xml:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/rest-assured/rest-assured/3.1.0/rest-assured-3.1.0.pom

Answer (score -1):

### Please find the below required maven dependencies for the Rest Assured project...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>RestAssured</groupId>
<artifactId>TestAPI</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>TestAPI</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>tagsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Optional dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```